# Get value from an object with variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a value from an object using a variable to select. I have tried `object[selected]` but it is coming back null and I also tried to convert object into list and retrieve by which # item I wanted.

object

```
{
"FOREX": ["NZD_USD", "EUR_USD", "EUR_GBP", "GBP_CAD"],
"S+p": ["AAPL", "TSLA", "MSFT", "UBER"],
"CRYPRO": ["ADABTC", "BTCGBP", "LINKBTC", "ETHBTC"],
}
```

function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const selected = state.Watchlist.watchlist.selected;
    const watchlists = state.Watchlist.watchlist.watchlists;
    const list = watchlists[selected];
    console.log(list)
};
```

selected console.log = `S+p`
watchlists console.log = the object above

right now list is undefined with the error `Watchlist.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

Comment: Please check selected and watchlists.
`console.log(selected)`
`console.log(watchlists)`

Comment: In my opinion, it is not a good way to check selected and watchlists in mapStateToProps

Comment: I think that is what is causing my problem, when I try to mess with the state in mapStateToProps my console log is changing from the actual values back to the INIT_STATE which is null. I'll try to move this out into another function.